# What does "one hit deaths" actually mean?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

After completing my latest game, I noticed the "one shot deaths" stat at the end. Since it was right below "one shot kills" I assumed that it was the number of my soldiers that were one-hit-killed by enemies.

However, I had only lost 4 soldiers: 3 in the tutorial mission (I accidentally had it on) and a single MEC trooper in the final mission to a Sectopod. The stat in question said 5.

So it's clear that my assumption of its meaning is incorrect. What is the correct interpretation of this 5?

Comment: Two things can I imagine causing this, first is that the counter does not reset when you reload the game during a mission, second is that captured enemy units died in one shots, mind controlled sectoids or hacked drones, the game has a habit of counting them as friendly deaths if they are under your control ( http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Medals#Notes )

Comment: @Paul I actually didn't use those much… I never captured any drones, and I only used a small amount of MC late-game, and most of the enemies I MC'd I killed with a few grenades.

Comment: I read this somewhere but I am not certain about it so I'll add it as a comment: There's a bug at the end of the game, when the big bad boss MC's one of your guys.
If you kill him, everything on his "Side" dies, so your MC'd character could of died also, but nothing became of it due to it initiating a cut-scene almost instantly, and then ending the game.

Comment: @IvardeBruin that can't be the case—I only had one MC'd soldier when I killed it. That wouldn't bring it from 3 to 5.

Comment: Might the loss of a MC'd soldier could as OHK for both you and them at the same time?

Comment: Thank you Stephen for asking on gaming.stackexchange. I can  safely assume @Paul is right. My reasoning is as follow: Upon completing the game on Ironman (XCOM option that prevents you to save at any time), final stats shows "Soldiers lost = 8" and "One shot kills = 13". Had no soldier MC by the aliens' big boss in final mission, though I abused of MC'ing them myself ;) This somehow invalidates the "bug at the end of the game" *in my case*. The difference of 5 between the two stats must equal to the number of aliens that were one shot killed while I MC them.

Answer (score 4):

As far as my own experience and other forums seem to be saying, one hit death does seem to be number of times friendlies have been one hit killed.

Therefore I can only assume that this was some form of bug or odd feature. I've found on one forum that apparently this sort of thing can happen at the end of the game when killing the boss:

*"There's a bug at the end of the game, when the big bad boss MC's one of your guys.
If you kill him, everything on his "Side" dies, so your MC'd character could of died also, but nothing became of it due to it initiating a cut-scene almost instantly, and then ending the game."* - Vexx303